# Cast a struct to a QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to knock up a pretty simple Qt program (as that's all I'm capable of!)...

...I've read a fairly small binary file into a QbyteArray and I can see that the QByteArray is holding that data correctly. I'd like to cast a pointer to a structure to the pointer to the data in the QByteArray so I can easily access the data in the file. However, it just doesn't work as I'd expect.

For example:

```
struct fileHeaderStruct
{

    uint16_t fileType;
    uint32_t fileSize;
    uint16_t reserved1;
    uint16_t reserved2;
    uint32_t startOffset;

};

QByteArray blob = file.readAll();
```

blob contains, at the start of its array of data:

42 4D 5E 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 04 00 00 28 00 00 00

If I cast a pointer to fileHeaderStruct to the data like so:

```
struct fileHeaderStruct* header;
header = (struct fileHeaderStruct*)blob.data();
```

header.fileType is correct as 0x4D42, but everything else is wrong

filesize is 0, reserved1 is 0, reserved2 is 0x436 and startOffset is 0x280000

fileSize should be 0x45E - it's completely lost those two bytes and showing the rest of the structure as if those two bytes didn't exist.

So, does anyone know why it has lost, or skipped, those two bytes please?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to include `struct` everywhere like you do, this isn't C. Just use `fileHeaderStruct* header;` instead of `struct fileHeaderStruct* header;`.

Comment: You should learn about structure padding and [structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: Thanks, CO. You have to do it in C (at least on the embedded environment I use) and so assumed you had to in C++!

Comment: @Joachim, I believe I have done the same kind of thing on 32-bit embedded processors without this kind of issue. Is this something that is specific to programming on a PC or am I just wrong about it not being an issue on, say, an ARM Cortex? I'll go knock up a test program on an STM32 to check...

Comment: Different compiler have different padding/alignment, especially on different platforms.

Comment: A quick and dirty Cortex M3 program shows the same behaviour with the gcc in C. I know last summer while working on a contract using IAR and C on a Cortex M3 we definitely cast structures to incoming serial messages with no such issues. Damn shame, makes life so much easier if it works as IAR! :D

Answer (score 2):

Read this: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/. Your structure packing is wrong for the order you have the members in. The default packing will align to machine word size, in this case almost certainly 32 bits.
I think:

```
#pragma pack(16)
struct fileHeaderStruct { ...

};
#pragma pack()
```

should give you the results you expect, depending on what compiler you're using.

Comment: __attribute__((packed)); was what did the trick. Found it in the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: What compiler are you using, BTW?

Comment: It's the gcc on Linux